# Find 'Execute SQL Task' component execution server (SQL Server Integration Services)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I've an 'Execute SQL Task' component in SSIS package.

```
Connection manager: 'Server A' 
Database: Finance_Warehouse 
SQL Query:   SELECT batch_date FROM Finance_Warehouse.etl_audit WHERE
   curr_batch_ind IS NULL 
SSIS Package: Runs from Server B
```

**My question:** When I execute SSIS package in 'Server B', where will 'Execute SQL Task' component SQL Query run? Server A or Server B?

Also, how do I verify that (on which server this component/SQL Query is running)?

My assumption is that, it will run on 'Server A' as SQL Server is installed in 'Server A', but looking for affirmed answer from experts.

Thanks in advance,

Ash

Trace details:

[image: trace details]

Comment: ConnectionManager is pointing to a specific database, your query will run on that database.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Is there an option to see where it being executed? a report/log etc?

Comment: SELECT db_name();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will run in Server A, you can view that by running the profiler/trace at the time of package is running.

(or)

You can also use DMV's. Run the below query in Server A or server B while your package is running, if the result shows the queries that is there in the package then that is the server where your query is executing.

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.session_id,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```

Refer Link: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/07/sql-server-find-currently-running-query-t-sql/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I ran trace and trying to understand where is the query running. Should I be looking into ServerName or HostName? I cannot attach screenshot here. So, have attached it to my main question.  Also, is there a way to monitor both Server A and Server B CPUs at the same time?

Comment: HostName - Name of the computer where the query is running.

Answer (score 0):

It Depends on how you set the ByPass Property of your task.

setting "BypassPrepare" property to true means, preparing (parsing) query is done by the database engine you are connecting to. Otherwise the preparation is done by integration services package.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Well, it is for parsing the query. I'm looking for evidence to see where the query is being executed.